# Let $X$ a non-Hausdorff topological space and let $\sim$ denote an equivalence relation on $X$. Is it possible that $X/\sim$ be Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ a non-Hausdorff topological space and let $\sim$ denote an equivalence relation on $X$. Is it possible that $X/\sim$ be Hausdorff? Show an example.

I would like to know also if there is a sufficient condition for $X/\sim$ to be an non-Hausdorff space.

Comment: Take any non-Hausdorff space $X$ and let $x \sim y$ for all $x,y \in X$.

Comment: If $x\sim y\iff x=y$ then $X/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $X.$

Comment: Another example. Let $Y$ be Hausdorff and $q\in Y$ and $X=Y\cup \{p\}$ with  $p\not \in  Y. $ Let $S\subset X$ be open in $X$ iff $[\,( p,q\not \in S$ and $S$ is open in $Y) \lor ( p,q \in S$ and $S$ \ $\{p\}$ is open in $Y)\,].$ Let $u\sim v$ iff $(\,u=v \lor \{u,v\}=\{p,q\}\,).$ Then $X/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $Y.$ The idea is to add a point $p$ to $Y$ such that $p$ and $q$ have the same nbhds in $X, $ and such that $Y$ (with its given topology) is a subspace of $X.$

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, yes, this is possible. Take, for example, the topological space
$$(X, \tau) = (\{1, 2, 3\}, \{\emptyset, \{1, 2\}, \{3\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\})$$
with equivalence relation
$$\sim \; = \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1) \}.$$
Then, if $\tau'$ is the quotient topology on $X / \sim$, then
$$(X / \sim, \tau') = (\{\{1, 2\}, \{3\}\}, \{\emptyset, \{\{1, 2\}\}, \{\{3\}\}, \{\{1, 2\}, \{3\}\}\}),$$
i.e. the discrete topology, which is definitely Hausdorff. However, $(X, \tau)$ is not Hausdorff, as $1$ and $2$ cannot be separated with open sets.

Comment: Thanks it already helped a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\mathbb{N} \cup \{p,q\}$ ($p,q$ distinct points not in the set $\mathbb{N}$) with the topology that $O$ is open iff $O \cap \{p,q\}=\emptyset$ or $\mathbb{N} \setminus O$ is finite. The points $p$ and $q$ cannot be separated by open sets so $X$ is not Hausdorff. $X$ is compact and $T_1$, though.

But the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ that has one non-singleton class $\{p,q\}$ has the property that $X/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to a convergent sequence and thus compact and Hausdorff (also metrisable).